# Understanding the Formal Definition of Sheaf

Tags: limits, sheaf-theory

A few questions based on the definitions at the end:

1. **The meaning of $a \rightsquigarrow b$** (#7 in abstract simplical complex definition). Not sure what "that is compatible with the inclusions of faces" means.
2. **If the sheaf vector spaces can be different types among the faces.** Or they all have to be the same type (#1 in first sheaf definition).
3. **If an abstract simplical complex is an open cover or related.** The second sheaf definition says a sheaf is on an open cover, while the first says it's on an abstract simplical complex.
4. **What the [inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) part is saying** (the second sheaf definition at the bottom): 
   $$F(Q)\to\varprojlim_{I\in N(Q)}F(U_I) =: F[Q]$$

---

The definitions of sheaf are from [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.4621.pdf).

An **abstract simplical complex** $X$ is:

1. Of a set $A$
2. A collection $X$ of subsets of $A$
3. Every element $x$ of $X$ (subset of $A$) implies that every subset of $x$ is in $X$.
4. Every $x$ in $X$ with $k+1$ elements is a k-face of $X$. This is the  *dimension*.
5. 0-dimensional faces are *vertices*.
6. 1-dimensional faces are *edges*.
7. A face $a$ "includes onto" $b$ ($a \rightsquigarrow b$) whenever $a$ is a proper subset of $b$.

A **sheaf** $F$ on an abstract simplical complex $X$ consists of:

1. A vector space $F(a)$ to each face of a of $X$ (the *stalk* at $a$).
2. A linear map $F(a \rightsquigarrow b) : F(a) \to F(b)$ (the *restriction* along $a \rightsquigarrow b$).
3. $F(b \rightsquigarrow c) \circ F(a \rightsquigarrow b) = F(a \rightsquigarrow c)$ whenever $a \rightsquigarrow b \rightsquigarrow c$.

> Given a simplicial complex, a sheaf is merely the assignment of vector-valued data to each face that is *compatible with the inclusions of faces*.

So to each face we assign a vector space. The face is a vertex of a graph if the face is 0-dimensional. The face is an edge of the graph if the face is 1-dimensional. So we assign vector space to each node and/or edge (and/or more if there's higher dimension). I think I understand that part. I don't understand the "is compatible with the inclusion of faces" part.

---

From the [full book](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.3255.pdf), the definitions are:

> A sheaf is a functor that commutes with limits coming from open covers.

Suppose $Λ = \{1, \dotsc , n\}$ is a finite discrete category.

The **open set category** is:

- Associated to a topological space $X$
- Denoted $\mathbf{Open}(X)$
- Whose objects are the open sets of $X$
- And whose morphisms $U \to V$ are for each pair related by inclusion $U \subseteq V$.

An **open cover** $Q$ is:

- Given a topological space $X$
- And an open set $U$ on $X$
- It's a collection of open sets on the open set $U$, $Q = \{U_i\}_{i\in Λ}$ whose union is $U$.

The **nerve** $N(Q)$ of an open cover $Q$:

- Gives us an abstract simplical complex $N(Q)$
- Elements are subsets of $Q$, $I = \{i_0, \dots ,i_n\}$
- (for which $U_I := U_{i_0} \cap \dots \cap U_{i_n} \neq \emptyset$

A **pre-sheaf** is:

- A functor $F : \mathbf{Open}(X)^{op} \to \mathbf{D}$

A **pre-cosheaf** is:

- A functor $\hat{F} : \mathbf{Open}(X) \to \mathbf{D}$

A **sheaf** $F$ is

- On $Q$ (open cover).
- If the unique map from $F(U)$ to the limit of $F \circ \rho^{op}_Q$ is an isomorphism, written:
  $$F(Q)\to\varprojlim_{I\in N(Q)}F(U_I) =: F[Q]$$

Comment: With respect to (4), the object $F(Q)$ cones the functor $F\circ \rho_Q^{op}$ in the following way: There is a natural restriction map $F(U)\to F(U_I)$ which commutes in the way you think it should. But because $F[Q]$ forms a "universal cone" to the aforementioned functor, there is a unique map $F(Q)\to F[Q]$ by the universal property of the limit. What the definition is saying is that this map is actually an isomorphism. Hence, you may identify $F(Q)$ with $F[Q]$.

Comment: So future answerers can better address your question, how familiar are you with category theory/limits?

Comment: I am reasonably familiar with intro category theory (categories, functors, morphisms) but not with limits in category theory since I haven't had an application for them yet.